# Quickblox FCM notification not working

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, quickblox

Im trying to use qb notifications , but I have problem.
I'm using sdk 3.3.4, reading from this [quickblox documentation](https://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-android)
in documentation I see that we need set QBNotificationChannel for FCM.
But we can set only GCM because we don't have FCM

```
public enum QBNotificationChannel {
    GCM("gcm"),
    APNS("apns"),
    APNS_VOIP("apns_voip"),
    EMAIL("email"),
    PULL("pull");

    private String caption;

    private QBNotificationChannel(String caption) {
        this.caption = caption;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.caption;
    }

    public String getCaption() {
        return this.caption;
    }

    public void setCaption(String caption) {
        this.caption = caption;
    }
}
```

Can any explain what I'm doing wrong?
Documentation look like wrong/broken. Not working anything. Auto subscribe not working not for gcm not for fcm. 
I can't create gcm notification, because google redirect me always on firebase.
In quickblox admin panel also I don't see settings for FCM , only for GCM.
AutoSubscription not working for GCM/FCM. Listeners not working.
I can only make hand subscribe, test send message from admin panel and than my subscription removed. 
Please any help?

Maybe someone already have some code with FCM and quickblox - please help.

Comment: two weeks and no answers also on qb support page. FCM cant be registered in manual way and auto subscribe working unstable for FCM. GCM is a way to continue work with qb notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FCM cant be registered in manual way and auto subscribe working unstable for FCM. GCM is a way to continue work with qb notifications. + when i ask - they have problem with server.

Answer (score 1):

For Me, its working.

I used quickblox dependencies

```
implementation "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-content:3.8.1"
    implementation "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-messages:3.8.1"
    implementation "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-customobjects:3.8.1"
    implementation "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:3.8.1"
```

and implement **FCM** with this. and its working great.

I just followed

```
https://docsdev.quickblox.com/android/Push_notifications.html#Platform_based_Push_Notifications
```

and for auto subscription, may be your SenderID is wrong becuase main reason for that is SenderID.

Hope it Helps.